# Fragment with ViewModel MVVM and event

Tags: java, android, mvvm

I have this case, and I'm a newbie on MVVM:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        RecipeSelectionListener,
        HomeFragment.MainActivityCallback,
        NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{
...
...
...
 @Override
    public void onRecipeSelected(RecipeEntity recipe, List<RecipeEntity> currentRecipeList) {
        List<String> listaIngredienti = fillSpinnerArray(currentRecipeList);
        // update data on fragment ViewModel with info on recipe selected
        homeViewModel.updateSelectedRecipe(recipe, currentRecipeList, listaIngredienti);
}
```

**HomeFragment.java**

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

...
...
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        homeViewModel =  new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(HomeViewModel.class);

        binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        View root = binding.getRoot();
        spinIngrediente = binding.spinIng;
spinAdapterIng = new ArrayAdapter<>(requireActivity(), R.layout.my_spinner, spinArrayIng);
        spinAdapterIng.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinIngrediente.setAdapter(spinAdapterIng);
        spinIngrediente.setSelection(positionSpinItem);
...
...
...
}


spinIngrediente.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
                positionSpinItem = position; //here i save the spinner position in a public variable
                UpdateData();
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
            }
        });

homeViewModel.getSpinnerItems().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), spinnerItems -> {
            spinArrayIng = spinnerItems;
            spinAdapterIng = new ArrayAdapter<>(requireActivity(), R.layout.my_spinner, spinnerItems);
                spinAdapterIng.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                spinIngrediente.setAdapter(spinAdapterIng);
            });

etTotRicetta.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                UpdateData();
            }
        });
    
    }
```

**HomeViewModel.java**

```
public class HomeViewModel extends ViewModel {

private MutableLiveData<List<String>> spinnerItems = new MutableLiveData<>();

public LiveData<List<String>> getSpinnerItems() {
        // Ottieni la lista di opzioni dal repository o da altre fonti
        return spinnerItems;
    }
public void updateSpinnerData(List<String> newData) {
        spinnerItems.setValue(newData);
    }
 public void updateSelectedRecipe(RecipeEntity recipe, List<RecipeEntity> newRecipeList, List<String> listaIngredienti) {
        currentIngRescale.setValue(recipe.getIngRescale());
        currentTotalRescale.setValue(recipe.getTotalRescale());
        spinnerItems.setValue(listaIngredienti);
        selectedRecipe.setValue(recipe);
        currentRecipeList.setValue(newRecipeList);
    }

}
```

In the MainActivity I select one recipe and I start the update by ViewModel (and all works!)

the question is, which are the correct method for work with MVVM when I have in the Fragment some events ( for ex. spinner or some edit TextChangedListener),

I work directly inside the Fragment or I have to work with ViewModel and come back to the MainActivity?
sorry for my newbie question

Comment: You can use Inside the Fragment there is no problem but if you want to put you can add state variables in ViewModel for Edittext

Comment: do you have one example for undertand better?

Comment: I have example but in Jetpack Compose I'm not working in XML currently.